# How to make two bones have the same rotation matrix?

Tags: armature, bones, coordinates

I have two bones. When i go in to pose mode an select each of them respectively, i can see that they have different coordinate systems / rotation matrices. How do i make them have the same Coordinate system / rotation matrix?
So the x-, y-, and z-axis is the same for each bone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select the bones you want to have the same coordinate system, *make sure that the Active bone is the one rotation matrix you want to give to the other*, now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to open the **'Recalculate Roll'** properties and choose ***Active Bone***.

[image]